# Solitons and traveling waves for a Schrödinger type equation

Tags: differential-equations, solitons, non-linear-schroedinger

I am a mathematician and not a physicist.
I came across a non--linear PDE whose linear part is a Schrödinger equation (i.e. a dispersive equation) and we know that this equation has a solution for $x\in\mathbb{T}$,
$$ u(t,x)=\frac{1}{1-a\, \mathrm{e}^{i(x-t)}}\,, $$
associated with an initial data $u_0(x)=\frac{1}{1-a\, \mathrm{e}^{ix}}\,,$ where $\mathbb{T}$ is the torus $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}\simeq [0,2\pi]$ (periodic domain), and $a$ is a complex constant on the open unit disc in $\mathbb{C}$, i.e. $|a|<1$.

We can observe that the solution $u$ is of the form $u(t,x)=u_0(x-t)$ which means that $u$ is a **traveling wave** solution. However, how do we know if this solution is a **soliton**?

What I have understood about *solitons is that there are traveling waves with the additional property that the wave retains its permanent structure, even after interacting with another soliton.*

Therefore, is it possible to determine whether $u$ defined above is a soliton by just looking at the solution's form, especially as the solution's propagation speed is constant?

Comment: *Schrödinger* might be a misleading term here, since it points in the direction of quantum physics, whereas the problem is really that of nonlinear dynamics (sometimes called *oscillations theory*). To my knowledge, Schrödinger-like non-linear equations arise in some limits from more general *Swift-Hohenberg equation*, which also produces sometimes solitary solutions. [Here is a paper](https://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~gfaye/articles/reviewCF.pdf) that came up in google, but which refers both to Schrôdinger and *solitary waves*(=solitons) - so you might find more following the links.

Comment: Still, it might be worth looking at the parallel developments in quantum, notably [Ginsburg-Landau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginzburg%E2%80%93Landau_theory) and [Gross-Pitaevskii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross%E2%80%93Pitaevskii_equation) - here a non-linear SE arises, but the object of study is more "*physical*".

Comment: Which diff. eq.?